# ASP.NET .NEt Framework Cpu Perfomance Issue with DomainBoundILStubClass and ThreadPoolworkQueue

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, threadpool

lastly i noticed a huge cpu perfomance issue while high of Http Request calling my web App.
so i tried to use Perfomance Profiler.
The Visual Studio performance profiler shows a high amount of CPU usage in the ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch and DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_COMtoCLR methods for an ASP.NET Entity Framework  application([image: as in Photo]). The CPU usage seems to increase with the number of incoming HTTP requests. I'm concerned this could be thread pool managment.

I've reviewd the code and i found no place where it week or bad implemented but still could not find solution for it
is there any suggestuion where i can start to improve the perfomance ?

Comment: In the context of "high of Http Request calling my web App", high CPU usage is nothing to surprise. Besides, native call stacks are less useful and you need to analyze managed call stacks instead. It requires a lot of experience to be able to properly interpret the data captured in a profiler, so hire an experienced consultant or involve Microsoft via https://support.microsoft.com. Nobody over the internet can magically tell the cause or suggest merely based on what you pasted above, and your concern is groundless right now.

Comment: Identify what is killing the CPU. I recommend [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).